# How to make loop with read file

Tags: node.js

I want to make a loop on node js with fs.readfile but I don't know how to do that.

These is my code:

```
const domain = "flickshot.id";
    const emailUname = replaceString(link, "https://generator.email/flickshot.id/", "");
    const getmsg = await functionGetMessages(domain, emailUname);
    console.log(getmsg);
    const verif = await functionVeryf(getmsg)
    console.log(verif);
```

I usually just use readline.question for that, but right now the link is more than one and I think it's better to use loop.

I've already tried with these one

```
const fulllink = await fs.readFile("x.txt", "utf8");
const link = fulllink.split("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < fulllink.length; i++){

  }
const domain = "flickshot.id";
    const emailUname = replaceString(link, "https://generator.email/flickshot.id/", "");
    const getmsg = await functionGetMessages(domain, emailUname);
    console.log(getmsg);
    const verif = await functionVeryf(getmsg)
    console.log(verif);
```

But I got these error:

TypeError: Expected input to be a string, got object

All I want with all of these code is, I put all link on (x.txt) and **const link** can read all of them. After that, I want to *const goto* work until all link has been open.

I hope you guys can help me to fix these, thank you so much.

**UPDATE:**

This is const for **functionGetMessages** and **functionVeryf**

```
const functionGetMessages = (domain, emailUname) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`https://generator.email/${domain}/${emailUname}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
            accept:
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            cookie: `_ga=GA1.2.659238676.1567004853; _gid=GA1.2.273162863.1569757277; embx=%5B%22${emailUname}%40${domain}%22%2C%22hcycl%40nongzaa.tk%22%5D; _gat=1; io=io=tIcarRGNgwqgtn40O${randstr(3)}; surl=${domain}%2F${emailUname}`,
            "upgrade-insecure-requests": 1,
            "user-agent":
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.text())
        .then(text => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(text);
            const src = $("a[name=staging_marlboro_id_auth_verify_ema]").attr('href');
            resolve(src);
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
});

const functionVeryf = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
        method: "get"
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(text => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(text);
            const src = $("p.staticp__text.mb50").text();
            resolve(src);
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
});
```

And for x.txt is:

```
https://generator.email/flickshot.id/erzajulliantdrf
https://generator.email/flickshot.id/erzajullian9o8e
etc
```

Comment: Hint: `await` only does something useful when used to `await` a promise.  So, if you're doing `await fn()`, then `fn()` needs to return a promise that resolves when the asynchronous operation is done.

Comment: `fs` also has synchronous versions of their functions you could use.. Instead of implementing your own async/await pattern using `fs`, you can use the built in synchronous methods to build your functions. More [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) on `fs` and more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) specifically on `fs.readFileSync`..

Comment: Also, it is not very clear what your end goal is.. What exactly do you want to accomplish? Are you wanting to recursively drill down into a file structure and add all file names with a certain extension to a .txt file? Or do you want to ask a user a question, have them type in an answer, then you add what they typed into a .txt file (or whatever type of file)? Please elaborate more on your goal, and share the code behind `functionGetMessages` and `functionVeryf`... Hard to help otherwise.

Comment: @MattOestreich hi, i've update code for functionGetMessages and functionVeryf, my goals is (I have a lot of links on my x.txt and I want to go to them in this case I want to make an auto verification email)

Comment: @MattOestreich So, x.txt is list of links i've, then functionGetMessages is I want to get link verification, and functionVeryf for verification. I hope you understand and can help me